# I dug a really deep hole in creative mode in minecraft but i didnt die and now im stuck in this weird area, what should i do?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I was in creative mode in minecraft and I got lost, so I dug a really really deep hole in the ground to I could die and then respawn where I began. I dug the hole and fell somewhere, but I don't know where I am. All I can see is the moon and sun. I can't move and I don't know what to do. Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: Sounds like you fell out the bottom of the map.  Yikes.

Comment: Why would you think that digging a hole would kill you?

Comment: Using F3 can tell you your coordinates so you know where you are, which is the first step to get out of there. Especially if your coords change when you try to move (then you move, but just don't see it) or you are really stuck in something.

Comment: What version of Minecraft, and is your game modded? If so, what mods?

Answer (score 3):

If you have cheats enabled:

The `\kill` command can be used to kill yourself to finish off your plan.

Use `/gamerule keepInventory true` in order to keep your inventory upon death.

Answer (score 2):

If you have cheats enabled, type /gamemode 3. This is Spectator Mode, which will let you fly through literally everything. You can't break nor pick up blocks though. Go into the ground and you'll see the caves around you. Use the space bar to go up, shift to go down, and the normal wasd to move yourself around the map. In this mode, nothing will attack you, so don't worry about dying from mob attacks. Just for fun while being in Spectator Mode: If you try to attack (left click) a mob, you'll see what they see. For example, if you attack a spider in Spectator Mode, you'll see what the spider sees, which is 8 slightly different screens. Also, I tend to write down coords of important places in my map, so I don't have to remember all of them. I hope this helped a bit. :)

Answer (score 2):

To get out of the weird area, double tap the button you use to jump. That will allow you to fly. Then keep going up until you reach land that you are under. You can destroy that land until you see light, then fly through. Double tap the button you use to jump again and you will stop flying. It may take a moment to reach the land depending on how long you have been falling. Make sure you are not over the hole when you stop flying.

Comment: lol. Thanks, that did it. Thanks for an alternative to cheat codes.

Answer (score 1):

You probably fallen into what's known as the void to escape you have several options:
IF CHEATS ARE OFF: enter the menu in the world -> open to lan -> switch cheats to on -> then open tolan
Once cheats are enabled:
/tp (x) (y) (z) will teleport you to target quardinates
/kill should kill you and return you to your spawnpoint
/gamemode (survival) (playername) will kill younreturning your body to spawnpoint
/tp (playername) (playername) will tp you to target player

If it persists to be A problem it may be a corrupt world save.

Answer (score -1):

Try typing `/tpx 0`...

You may have to open the game to lan to enable cheat commands (both things are temporary, don't worry)

Comment: `/tpx` only works if he's got Mystcraft installed (and if he did, it would work, as he'd be teleported to spawn in dimension 0 (the overworld)). But I'm not certain his game is modded, he didn't mention it.